# Will windows 10 install 32 or 64 bit

Tags: windows

I was wondering if windows 10 will install as 32 bit or 64 bit, because one of my computers has a x64 processor with 32 bit windows 7 on it, but I want it to install 64 bit windows 10, will it already do that? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot upgrade a Windows 7 or Windows 8.1 Update x86 installation to Windows 10 x64 installation. If you want to do that you will have to first upgrade your installation, then using the [x64 .ISO](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=616936), install Windows 10 x64 and perform a clean install.  Doing this will wipe all your personal files so perform a backup before you do it.

Comment: If you're talking about the Free Upgrade offer, it will be upgrading your existing OS, so it will not change the bit-ness of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

According to [This article](http://www.intowindows.com/upgrade-to-windows-10-64-bit-from-windows-78-1-32/), the OS will upgrade as 32-bit.  After successful install, you will be able to do a clean install of the 64-bit OS.

This is confirmed by a few Technet articles etc which I have read, however I havent been able to test this in the real world though as all my kit is already 64-bit.

Comment: This has been the case since there has been an in-place upgrade process.  You have never been able to upgrade a x86 installation to a x64 installation.  This is technically true with Linux, although in that case, given enough skill it can be done.